# Como fazer a stream de um arquivo do meu servidor?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, vbscript

Pessoal gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer um tipo de arquivo compartilhável, por exemplo: Tenho um arquivo chamado bots.txt no meu servidor, gostaria que meu clientes pudessem editar ele através da web ficando salvo no meu servidor. Segue um exemplo do Onedrive: [Arquivo](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21APcBKSINl8IahXE&v=TextFileEditor&id=2DC45E11D8DC78B3%216849&cid=2DC45E11D8DC78B3&parId=2DC45E11D8DC78B3%21106). Pode ser resolvido em qualquer linguagem.

> Minha necessidade é fazer isso sem precisar do Onedrive no qual possam adicionar nomes de preferência sem apagar os já existentes(não tem problemas caso ainda possam apagar).

Comment: Você já tem algo pronto? Algum código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples:

```
 /project
      txt_edit.php
      text.txt
```

Código-txt_edit.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
   $re = fopen("text.txt" , 'w');
   $write = fwrite($re ,$_POST['text']);
   if($write){
      echo "<script> alert('Conteúdo alterado') </script>";
   }else if($write == false ){
      echo "<script> alert('O correu um erro')</script>";
  }
}
$fp = fopen("text.txt" , "r");
echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
echo '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="50">';
while(!feof($fp)){
    $buffer = fgets($fp , 4096);  
    echo $buffer;    
}
echo '</textarea><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Salvar">';
echo '</form>';
```

Para adicionar apenas uma linha sem ver o conteúdo:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $fp = fopen("text.txt" , "r");    
    $lines = '';
        while(!feof($fp)){
           $lines .= fgets($fp , 4096) ;               
        }       
    fclose($fp);
    $re = fopen("text.txt" , 'w');  
    $lines .= $_POST['text'];       
    $write = fwrite($re , $lines . PHP_EOL);  
    if($write){
        echo "<script> alert('Conteúdo alterado') </script>";
  }else if($write == false ){
      echo "<script> alert('O correu um erro')</script>";
  }
}

echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
echo '<input type="text" name="text" rows="20" cols="50">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Salvar">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: E como faço pra adicionar um nome abaixo do outro? Sem que vejam o que já tem salvo no arquivo? Tipo só possam adicionar, não podem ver nem editar os nomes existentes?

Comment: Editei a resposta verifique se resolve o problema ;)

Answer (score 1):

Com php você pode usar o **[fopen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)**

```
$arquivo = "bots.txt";
fopen($arquivo, "r+"); // abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita
$linhas = "";
while(!feof($arquivo)){
    $linhas .= fgets($arquivo, 1024)."\n"; // adiciona linhas
}
```

Com isso você pode implementar um editor para apagar ou inserir linhas:

```
<textarea><?php echo $linhas; ?></textarea>
```

Para escrever você utiliza o `fwrite`

```
fopen($arquivo, "r+"); // abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita
fwrite($arquivo, $_POST['textarea']); // altera o arquivo com o valor
```

No String Mode você tem as seguintes opções:

> **'r'**   Abre somente para leitura; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no começo
>   do arquivo.
>
> **'r+'**  Abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no
>   começo do arquivo.
>
> **'w'**   Abre somente para escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no começo
>   do arquivo e reduz o comprimento do arquivo para zero. Se o arquivo
>   não existir, tenta criá-lo.
>
> **'w+'**  Abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no
>   começo do arquivo e reduz o comprimento do arquivo para zero. Se o
>   arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo.
>
> **'a'**   Abre somente para escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no final
>   do arquivo. Se o arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo.
>
> **'a+'**  Abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no
>   final do arquivo. Se o arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo.
>
> **'x'**   Cria e abre o arquivo somente para escrita; coloca o ponteiro no
>   começo do arquivo. Se o arquivo já existir, a chamada a fopen()
>   falhará, retornando FALSE e gerando um erro de nível E_WARNING. Se o
>   arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo. Isto é equivalente a especificar
>   as flags O_EXCL|O_CREAT para a chamada de sistema open(2).
>
> **'x+'**  Cria e abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro
>   no começo do arquivo. Se o arquivo já existir, a chamada a fopen()
>   falhará, retornando FALSE e gerando um erro de nível E_WARNING. Se o
>   arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo. Isto é equivalente a especificar
>   as flags O_EXCL|O_CREAT para a chamada de sistema open(2).